# jQuery Get Attribute Value even when it changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
$(".bg .thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
    $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

So every time I click on a new background, it is highlighted and is given a class "active" and the previous active class is removed.

Now all I need to do is create a variable and set it to the data-name attribute for that active item.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="thumb_wrapper active">
    <img src="images/backgrounds/thumb/bg2.jpg" data-name="bg2.jpg">
</div>
```

So if I put it in the click function, it will work fine:

```
var bg = $(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img").attr("data-name");
console.log(bg);
```

so every time it is clicked, it tells me the value.  But I need to access that variable outside of that function.. so it needs to be global.

Is there anything I can do to grab the value of data-name on the start of the page, not on a click function?  And when I do click a new BG and the active class is updated, then the variable will be updated also?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me...

Comment: Just define `var bg` in global scope and update it inside `.click` handler.

Comment: also, use .data, not .attr.. ex: $(el).data("name")

Comment: Is defining 'bg' outside the click listener and updating the new reference on click not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the function so its scope is not limited to the click handler.

```
var bg;

$(".bg .thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
   $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   bg = $(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img").data("name");
});

console.log(bg); //accessible outside
```

If you want the value of `bg` to be updated everytime a new BG is clicked, you must do the assignment in the click handler as above.

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8ptw/2/)

Comment: For some reason, it won't work!  if I move console.log inside the function, it works.. but the code you have right there won't work for me. :(

Comment: It doesn't because the `console.log()` statement won't get called, since it is not in the click handler. The code above is an example that `bg` can be accessed gloablly

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is define the variable outside of the click-handlers, but presumably within the `$(document).ready()`, but update it in the various click-handlers (or whatever other handlers you're using):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bg = $(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img['data-name']").attr("data-name") || '';
/* all the other JavaScript/jQuery, click handlers and so forth... */
});
```

In this instance, the variable will be equal to the `data-name` attribute of the img with a `data-name attribute` or, if none such exists, will be set to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for what you need,

1. Define `var bg` in global scope and update it inside `.click` handler
2. Just call `$(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img").attr("data-name");` whenever you want to know the value of `.active`'s `data-name`

**CODE:**

```
var bg;
$(function () {
  $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
    $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    bg = $(this).attr("data-name");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, use $(el).data("name") to get the data attributes value, not .attr, and if you do that on start up, it will get the value if it's there;

Javascript is functionally scoped, meaning when you define it in the click handler's function you won't have access from outside of that function. Instead define the variable and assign in in a higher scope, like DOM Ready, like so:

```
$(function() {
    var bg = $(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img").data("name");
});
```

bg will have the value when the page loads.. And accessible from any internal functions, such as click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create and set the variable bg on page load, then update it each time a thumbnail is clicked?

If so, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bg = $(".bg .thumb_wrapper.active img").attr("data-name");
    $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
        $(".bg .thumb_wrapper").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        bg = $(this).attr("data-name");
    });
});
```